# $S$ is of measure zero iff it is of volume zero

Tags: calculus

Can anyone give me a hint how to prove this:

> If $S\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $S$ is compact then as every open cover has a finite sub-cover , $S$ is of measure zero if and only if $S$ is of volume zero .

Comment: What are your definitions of measure and volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ has content (volume) $0$, then for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a finite collection of open rectangles $\{R_1,R_2,\ldots, R_n\}$ covering $S$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} vol(R_i) < \epsilon.$$

Thus content $0$ implies measure $0$.

On the other hand, if $S$ has measure $0$, then there is a countable collection of open rectangles covering $S$ with the above property.  Now use the fact that $S$ is compact to conclude $S$ has content $0$.

Comment: Can you also state the definition of content (volume)? Thanks.

Comment: @John:  The volume of a closed rectangle $R = [a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]\times \ldots \times [a_n,b_n]$ is $\prod_{i}(b_i-a_i)$. The same applies to an open rectangle.

Comment: so what is the content (volume) of a compact set?

Comment: For an arbitrary set -- we use Lebesgue (product) measure.  For this exercise we only need the concept of measure 0.